# Type in functional programming (OCaml)

Tags: types, functional-programming, ocaml, signature

I am learning functional programming and I am not understanding the types in OCaml, and I have not found anything real helpful.

I have this code:

```
let rec map2 f l1 l2 =
          match (l1,l2) with
          ([], _) -> []
        | (_, []) -> []
        | (x::l1s,y::l2s) -> (f x y) :: map2 f l1s l2s;;


let pick n m =
      if n > m then (fun b x -> if b then x+1 else x*2)
      else (fun b x -> if b then x+2 else x*4);;

map2 (pick 7 9) [true;false] [3;4;5;6];;
```

What I find difficult to understand the steps to know the type of this kind of functions (map2, pick).

I know a little bit how signature works, the right associative property and that the symbol " **'** " refers to a generic type.

solution:

```
pick: 'a -> 'a -> bool -> int -> int = <fun>
map2: ('a->'b->'c) -> 'a list -> 'b list -> 'c list
```

I don't understand why bool -> int and why in map bool isn't in the function parameter.

Any reference to books, link, is welcomed

Comment: The word "signature" has a very specific meaning in OCaml. What you need is not called "signature", but simply "type".

Comment: @n.m.thank you, I will edit

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic on SO (See [help/on-topic]), but your question is also so fundamental that proper understanding requires more than what can be given in an answer. You should read through [Real World OCaml](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/), and in particular [the section on type inference and inferring generic types](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/guided-tour.html#scrollNav-2-1). Then when you come back, please try to ask specific answerable questions.

Comment: Why would you expect `bool` to be a parameter of `map2`? Which one?

Comment: @n.m. I have pick 'a -> 'a -> bool -> int -> int, why in map2 I have ('a -> 'b -> 'c) as parameters of function pick?

Comment: map2 knows absolutely nothing about pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pick: 'a -> 'a -> bool -> int -> int = <fun>
map2: ('a->'b->'c) -> 'a list -> 'b list -> 'c list
```

What you see here is a process in functional programming called **currying**. To make sense of this, let's consider a simpler example. Let's say you have a function `f` that takes 2 arguments `X` and `Y`, and output `Z`. How we usually write this is

```
f(X, Y) = Z
```

Let's see this in a different way - we have a function `f`, and if we give it `X`, and then `Y`, it will gives us `Z`. What would happen if we only give `f` 1 argument, `X`? Let's test it out!

```
let plus a b = a + b;;
```

This code defines a function `plus`, which takes 2 arguments `a` and `b` and returns their sum. If you type `plus 1 1;;` into `utop`, it will give you `2`. Now, the output when you type

```
plus 1;;
```

is

```
- : int -> int = <fun>
```

This means `plus(1)` actually produces a FUNCTION that takes an `int` and output an `int`! Wait a minute, initially we have a function that produces integer, and suddenly the same function is producing ... FUNCTION? What's going on?

**The key idea here is to think of a function as a process that consumes the arguments one by one**. In the spirit of this, the function `plus` above is like a process that consumes 2 arguments: if you give it just 1 argument, it would stall and wait for the 2nd argument. And this stalled process is exactly similar to a process that consumes 1 argument: give it the remaining ingredient and it would start grinding to give you the expected output.

To see how this perspective can help you make sense of the obscure way in which function signature is written in your example, let's look at the function `pick`:

```
let pick n m =
  if n > m then (fun b x -> if b then x+1 else x*2)
  else (fun b x -> if b then x+2 else x*4);;
```

`pick` takes in 2 arguments, `n` and `m`, and output a function `f` that takes in 2 arguments `b` and `x`. The definition of `f` depends on a comparison.
If `n > m`, then it outputs a function `fun b x` whose definition is `if b then x+1 else x*2`.
Else, it outputs a function `fun b x` whose definition is `if b then x+2 else x*4`.

If we were to write a rough signature for `pick` based on the above understanding, it would be something like:

```
pick: (n, m) -> (function f that takes in b and x, and output some number)
```

In light of our understanding of currying, `pick` is like a process that consumes `n`, and then `m`. So the signature can be written in this way too:

```
pick: n -> m -> (function f that takes in b and x, and output some number)
```

Oh hey, this function `f` can also be thought of as a process that consumes `b` and then `x`, so we can also write:

```
pick: n -> m -> (b -> x -> some number)
```

which looks strikingly similar to:

```
pick: 'a -> 'a -> bool -> int -> int = <fun>
```

Now, as of how the heck does OCaml know that `b` is supposed to be `bool`, and `x` and `some number` is supposed to be `int`, OCaml has a featured called **type inference**. Basically speaking, the compiler looks at the operations you perform on the variables and try to make a guess of their types. E.g. I see `if b` in the code, so probably `b` should be a `bool`.

**In summary**, that obscure way in which the function signature is written is called **currying**, and how OCaml knows `b` is a `bool` is through a feature called **type inference** in OCaml. This should makes it easier for searching.

Comment: @user4789408 From the signature alone, you can see that `map2` takes 3 arguments: a function with signature `('a -> 'b -> 'c)`, a `'a list`, and a `'b list`; and it outputs a `'c list`. When you compare this with the actual definition of the function things would make sense: indeed `map2` takes 3 arguments which are `f`, `l1` and `l2`, and output a list: if either `l1` or `l2` is empty output an empty list, otherwise apply function `f` on the first elements `x` and `y` of the 2 lists and concatenate that with the recursive result of `map2` on the remaining elements of the 2 lists

Answer (score 1):

If you look at pick then you see that it takes 2 argument and then returns a function. What it returns is (same for the other fun):

```
(fun b x -> if b then x+1 else x*2)
```

The "if" construct is of the form `if <bool> then <'a> else <'a>`. So b must be bool while x can still be 'a. Going deeper there is `x+1`. So x must be `int` and the result is `int` too.

So the above function is `bool -> int -> int` and hat is shown in the type of pick.

As for map2: The map2 function can work with any function of the form `'a -> 'b -> 'c` as first argument. In your example you pass `bool -> int -> int` but this does not limit map2 to that type. Your code could continue with

```
let pick_f n m =
      if n > m then (fun b x -> if b then x +. 1. else x *. 2.)
      else (fun b x -> if b then x +. 2. else x *. 4.);;

map2 (pick_f 7 9) [true;false] [3.;4.;5.;6.];;

pick_f: 'a -> 'a -> bool -> float -> float = <fun>
```

The same map2 function is used but here with `bool -> float -> float` as type of the first argument. The map2 function is polymorphic (what you called generic) and can work with many types.